# Android scaling and touch issue

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, onclicklistener

I'm working on an android app that allows users to upload images to my server. On the selection screen, I allow them to scale the images using pinch to zoom, and then they select the image by tapping it. I ran into two problems while implementing it.

The first problem I ran into was while I was using an `OnClickListener` to detect when the images were clicked. That prevented me from scaling the images up or down as long as my fingers were over the images. I implemented it like this:

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        ToggleSelection();
        invalidate();
    }
});
```

Since I want them to still be able to scale the images even with their fingers over the images, I decided to go with my second approach. I added an `OnTouchListener` instead.

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        int i = event.getAction();
        Log.d("TouchInfo123","Event action: " + i);
        switch(i & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            ToggleSelection();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then I noticed that the `event.getAction()` was always returning 0, the value for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. So I switched to listening for the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` which works. Kind of.

The problem I'm running into now, is that when I go to scale the images, if my fingers touch one of the images, it toggles the selection which can get really annoying.

I would like to be able to do one of two things:

Use an `OnClickListener` but allow my `ScaleGestureDetector` to scale the images even if my fingers are touching the images

**or**

Make the `OnTouchListener` work with the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` so that I know they're not scaling when it gets the touch event fired.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around this issue. The reason I wasn't able to get `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` was because I was always returning false so I wasn't consuming the event. I went with this to make it work like I expected

```
boolean mouseDown = false;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    {
        if(mouseDown)
        {
            ToggleSelection();
            invalidate();
            mouseDown = false;
        }
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
    {
        mouseDown = false;
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    {
        mouseDown = true;
        return true;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```